# Can you QuickSilver Sash or Cleanse out of Poppy's Ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

The question is summed up in the title. What happens exactly?

Comment: While I agree that your title is a very direct question, it really helps the site out if you provide a little more information in the question description rather than "see title". For example, you could list what the QuickSilver Sash, Cleanse, and Poppy's Ult do as supporting text for why you asked the question. :)

Comment: Not everyone watches Rift Myths you know.

Comment: I will try to be more descriptive next time. My apologies, but I've never heard of Rift Myths.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot completely cleanse or quicksilver sash out of poppy's ultimate for a very specific reason:

Poppy's ultimate is NOT wholy a debuff on your champion. There are two parts:

One is a buff applied to poppy granting her certain invulnerability to other enemy units. This cannot be touched.

The other is a debuff on your champion increasing the damage you take from poppy. This CAN be QSSed.

Comment: This was covered on [episode 4 of Rift Myths](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0JezdX20vM&t=0m7s).

Answer (score 0):

According the video below (Riftmyths 4), no.

[http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=g0JezdX20vM#t=10s](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0JezdX20vM)

QSS doesn't appear to do anything. Since the video is from Cho'Gath's perspective, we can see the debuff applied and QSS does not remove it.

Comment: Read my answer. You're wrong.